# Term `neither` in a compound negation

Tags: phrases, negation, compounds

Here is an example:

> 1. My father did not visit the exhibition and neither did I.

Is it OK to say the same in the following way:

> 2. My father did not visit the exhibition and so did I.

Is there any difference in the meaning?

Comment: Number one makes perfect since. Number two makes no sense. "neither did" would me you both did not do something, "so did", would mean you both did do something. You have to match up with the first instance in the sentence.

Comment: **neither** does not mean **also**.

Comment: @TRomano I am not sure how to put the question correctly, I removed the conflict for now. I fear it sounds too generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase **and so does** when it joins two clauses means "and the same *positive* assertion is true of"  (emphasis on *positive assertion*).

> John has brown eyes **and so does** Jane.

John has brown eyes and the same assertion is true of Jane. She too has brown eyes.

The phrase **and neither does** when it joins two clauses means "and the same *negative* assertion is true of"  (emphasis on *negative assertion*).

> John does not have blue eyes **and neither does** Jane.

John does not have blue eyes, and the same assertion is true of Jane. She too does not have blue eyes.

P.S. The predicate of the second clause is implicit (*have brown eyes*...*not have blue eyes*).

Answer (score 2):

English grammar, aside, your second sentence doesn't make *logical* sense.  If your father did one thing and you did the opposite, we would expect to see a "but" to indicate there is going to be a change in direction:

> My father did not visit the exhibition **but** I did.

Otherwise you want to say that you did the same thing:

> My father did not visit the exhibition, and I didn't either.

Your first example says this more concisely:

> My father didn't [do X] and neither did I.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use **also** like this. We could use it in the way you want to, but we don't.

My father did not visit the exhibition and I did not also. No matter how we try to word it, it is awkward in English. The word is used consistently to mean an positive assertion, not a negative assertion/negation.

(from Google Dictionary)

> also adverb in addition; too. "a brilliant linguist, he was also
>   interested in botany" synonyms:   too, as well, besides, in addition,
>   additionally, furthermore, further, moreover, into the bargain, on top
>   (of that), what's more, to boot, equally; More